# Ubuntu 16.04 lags in VM

Tags: virtualbox, performance, screenshot

So, first of all, I'm new to Linux. I am using Ubuntu with windows 8.1 in virtual box. Updated. Even my host (windows) starts to hang whenever I start the machine. I seriously want to use Ubuntu. And also i can't take screenshots either. They're always blank.

I've also installed guest editions, done `sudo apt-get update` and what not.

System's RAM-8 GB
RAM allocated-2 GB
CPU intel(R) core(TM) i5-5250U@ 1.60GHz

Comment: How much RAM do you have in your host machine? How much did you give to the VM? Do you have a bunch of programs using the disk in the background? Do you have a good CPU? What about your GPU?

Comment: Edit your question with these details 1) Your system's total RAM 2) Allocated RAM for Ubuntu VM.

Comment: @Android Dev @ Anwar I edited the question. It also takes too much time to boot. 5 to 10 minutes.

Comment: Could you please provide the **exact** model of your CPU?

Comment: intel(R) core(TM) i5-5250U

Comment: Set VM settings to use 2 CPU's and see if that doesn't help. Cheers, Al

Comment: @SanatKumar Your CPU is not bad and I think, you should allocate more RAM to the VM. give it 3GB and see what it does. Also give it 2 Core as heynnema suggested

Comment: Did you enable VT-X in the BIOS?

Comment: @heynnema  I already did that and it was of no help.

Comment: @Anwar Giving it 3GB RAM might have changed a little bit. I guess I'll stop using Firefox on Ubuntu. It still is too laggy. That might help a bit. Though it still took a lot of time to boot.

Comment: @ Android Dev Yes, it was already enabled.

Comment: How much memory have you committed to video memory? Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema 32 MB

Comment: @SanatKumar You should give it more video memory. 32 MB would be too low

Comment: Allocate 128MB to the video. Reboot, and see if that helps. Cheers, Al

Comment: @ Anwar @heynnema Alright. Just allocated 128MB and rebooted. Stared at a black screen with a blinking ' - ' (dash) for about 30 minutes and then there was nothing on the screen. Waited for 20 minutes more. Then i reset the machine. Again. Ended up with black screen. Rebooted the host system. Started Ubuntu again. This time without the full screen mode. Works smooth. I think there's something about full screen.

Answer (score 1):

You have a poor processor for run a virtual machine with Ubuntu. Unity will take a lot of resources that your system can't handle efficiently. I recommend to use Lubuntu in your case. Or even better, do a dual boot. But be aware of install Ubuntu with Unity. Install Xubuntu, or Lubuntu. First of all, try booting a live USB or live DVD to try the *buntu distro that fits better to your system specs, after this, you can decide if dual boot, or run in a virtual machine.

To install Guest Addtitions, insert the Guest Additions CD from the devices menu. Then, search the mounted media and enter the folder, you will see a file named like "VBoxLinuxAdditions.run". From a console, run:

```
sudo sh ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

If it fails, install:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
sudo apt-get intall build-essential
```

The installation will give you some information about other packages and related information about a possible failure.

Regards.

Comment: VB runs fine on my i5. Cheers, Al

Answer (score -1):

Go to *Settings* >> *Proseccors* then change CPU amount to 2 (or more) CPUs.

[image]

Comment: -1 Ubuntu runs fine with one (virtual) CPU. The cause of the issue must be something else.

Comment: If that doesn't work, don't blame me.